# Excel: How to find the value of in the cell which is highlighted without directly referencing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[image]

Quick for excel: How can I find the value of in the cell which is highlighted in green without directly referencing? Do I have to use the VBA? Are there any other easier ways?

Comment: VBA is the only way to find a cell by it's color (other than the manual Find Format)

Comment: It seems odd to me that one person should set the green highlight and another looking for it. Once you think of automation, it should be possible to combine the two processes for greater efficiency.

Comment: what are your criteria for finding the cell?  is the highlight for our benefit or was the a method for determining which cell to highlight?

Comment: If the cell has a real formatting with a standart color, you could use `Get.Cell` as a XLM in an `IF` for the range by checking the color to not be zero. Wrap a `SUM` around it and you will get just the value. By doing this at *named range* you can avoid VBA.

Comment: Don't understand the question. Are you saying you want to find the cell based on the colour of the cell or the value of the cell? If it's the colour, you could use something like conditional formatting perhaps but that really depends on your requirement. If it's the value, there are different ways to approach that, again based on what your actual requirement is?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote some small VB code on the cell selected to find the value based on the color

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GoGreen()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A4:P19")
    
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 14 Then ActiveCell.Value = cell.Value
    
Next cell
    
End Sub
```